# Simple column non working in reportclass

Tags: columns

I have been using `beamer` and therein I use `columns` in this way:

```
\begin{columns}[t]
    \justifying
    \column{0.45\textwidth}
    something1    
    \column{0.45\textwidth}
    something2
\end{columns}
```

It returns error when compiling in `report`:

```
! LaTeX Error: Environment columns undefined.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
```

How can I modify it to `report`?

Here a **MWE**:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[headheight=18pt,a4paper, width=150mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm, bindingoffset=6mm, headsep=18pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish,es-noquoting]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[activate={true,nocompatibility},final,tracking=true,kerning=true,spacing=true,factor=1100,stretch=10,shrink=10]{microtype}

\begin{document}
\begin{columns}[t]
    \justifying
    \column{0.45\textwidth}
    something
    ni
    ce

    \column{0.45\textwidth}
    something2
    ni 
    ce
    \end{columns}
\end{document}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [multicol](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/multicol) package:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[headheight=18pt,a4paper, width=150mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm, bindingoffset=6mm, headsep=18pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish,es-noquoting]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[activate={true,nocompatibility},final,tracking=true,kerning=true,spacing=true,factor=1100,stretch=10,shrink=10]{microtype}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}% 2 => 2 columns, justified
    something
    ni
    ce

    \columnbreak
    something2
    ni
    ce
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Good. Can the width be controlled?

Comment: @Schopenhauer The width is setting automatically from `\linewidth` and the number of columns, but you can probably override it by setting `\columnwidth` (I have never tried). You can also set the `\columnsep`, `\columnseprule` and various other parameters. The manual is quite readable.